# Remote desktop freezes when there's a lot of scrolling text

Tags: remote-desktop, scrolling

when I connect to a Windows 2008 server via remote desktop (rdesktop ir krdc - doesn't matter) it works fine until there is a lot of scrolling text. Let's say I open a ssh connection to some other server (from the terminal) and run tcpdump. The remote desktop completely freezes other than the window with the scrolling text.

The connection between my PC and the server is 100mbps WAN.

I imagine this happens because rdp does not want to drop frames so it buffers all the text and tries to play it out over the connection. Is there a way to make rdp drop frames in this case so that I miss most of the scrolled text but the connection is responsive and does not build up 20 seconds of lag?

Comment: This seems like a client side issue related to rdesktop / krdc. I am not seeing such behavior on the client side in MSTSC or any of the platform-specific clients. You might have more luck contacting the respective dev-teams / projects: http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc/ and http://www.rdesktop.org/#lists

Comment: I tried it with Remote Desktop client in Windows 7. A bit better but the problem remains - ssh'ing to a server and doing a cat /big/file or, worse, tcpdump is a good way of making the terminal lag behind by 10 seconds or more.

Comment: I've got same problem with MSTSC from Windows 10 to Windows 10.